# Meditation with texts in a text file in the case of threading

Tags: python, python-2.7

iam using this code to to pull the first line at text file at threading mod before delete it from the file

```
with open(r'C:\datanames\names.txt','r') as fin:
                   name = fin.readline()
            
with open(r'C:\datanames\names.txt', 'r') as fin:
                    data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
with open(r'C:\datanames\names.txt', 'w') as fout:
                    fout.writelines(data[1:])
```

put it make me lose the data Often
Is there a more efficient and practical way to use it in such a situation? (threading)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to use threading for this. It's very straightforward.

To remove the first line from a file do this:

```
FILENAME = 'foo.txt'

with open(FILENAME, 'r+') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.seek(0)
    file.writelines(lines[1:])
    file.truncate()
```